# Finding a cubic polynomial whose splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ equals $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ if $a$ is any of its roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

**Question:** Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the roots of a rational cubic polynomial $q$. Can we find a (non-trivial) example where the splitting field of $q$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ equals $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha), \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$?

**Comments:** This is from an old algebra exam. Clearly one solution (the one given by the professor) is $q(x)=(x-1)^3$ where the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(1) = \mathbb{Q}$, but I was wondering: does there exist a $q$ as described above so that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$  = $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$ but still so that they are different from $\mathbb{Q}$? If not, can we prove that it does not exist?

Comment: What about $x^3-1$? Its splitting field is generated by a single root, but that doesn't quite fit your question because you have to be careful which root you choose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Yes. The basic construction is actually quite simple. You want a Galois extension to be generated by your root, so that--by normality--any separable polynomial with a single root in the field splits completely.

Since the degree is $3$, this means we want an extension with Galois group $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. By general theory we know that [all abelian extensions are contained within cyclotomic extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem) (or at least that all cyclotomic extensions are abelian, that's enough to find an example.)

So let us look at numbers $n$ such that $3|\varphi(n)=[\Bbb Q(\zeta_n):\Bbb Q]$, where here $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity and $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Such a number is $n=7$. Then within $\Bbb Q(\zeta_7)$ we have a Galois subfield of degree $3$, which is fixed, therefore, by any element of order $2$ because $\varphi(7)=6=2\cdot 3$. Since Complex conjugation is one such (indeed the only one), we see that $\Bbb Q\left(\cos\left({2\pi\over 7}\right)\right)=\Bbb Q\left(\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}\right)=\Bbb Q(\zeta_7)\cap\Bbb R$ is a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ of degree $6/2=3$. Hence the polynomial $q$ can be taken to be the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Furthermore, if you want to compute the polynomial explicitly, you can always do the trick where you compute the characteristic polynomial of multiplication by $\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}$ on the basis $\{1,\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}, \zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2}\}$ for $\Bbb Q\left(\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}\right)$, which gives the matrix

> $$\begin{pmatrix}
> \cdot & |& 1 & \zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1} & \zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2} \\
> --- &\cdot & --- & --- & ---\\
> 1 & | & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1} & | & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
> \zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2} & | &-1 & 0 & -1
> \end{pmatrix}$$

with characteristic polynomial

> $$q(x) = \begin{vmatrix}
> x & -1 & 0 \\
> -2 & x & -1 \\
> 1 & 0 & x+1
> \end{vmatrix} = x^3 +x^2-2x-1$$

which is an explicit example.

---

**Nitty gritty in case you haven't done many of those computations:**

The idea is to take a basis for $\Bbb Q\left(\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}\right)$ and look at the matrix which comes out of multiplying this basis by $\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}$. I chose the basis $\{1, \zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}, \zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2}\}$. How does multiplication by $\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}$ affect this?

It does this

$$\begin{cases}
1\mapsto \zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1} \\
\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}\mapsto (\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1})^2=2\cdot 1+1\cdot(\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2}) \\
\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2}\mapsto \zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^{-3}+\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}
\end{cases}$$

Now we know that the sum of all $n^{th}$ roots of unity is $0$, so we do write that here as

$$1+\zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^{-3}+\zeta_7^{-2}+\zeta_7^{-1}=0$$

so that we have $\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^{-3}=-1-(\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1})-(\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2})$ which makes the last case

$$\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2}\mapsto -1\cdot (1)\cancel{-1\cdot (\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1})}+\cancel{1\cdot (\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1})}-1\cdot(\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2})$$
$$=-1\cdot(1)-1\cdot(\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^{-2})$$

Each of these give us the rows of the matrix.

Finally, one just computes the characteristic polynomial and that produces the $q$ I showed above.

Comment: +1 for this is the first example that occured to me, too. It may be worth pointing out that the conjugates of $\alpha=\cos(2\pi/7)$ are $\beta=\cos(4Pi/7)=2\alpha^2-1$ and $\gamma=\cos(8\pi/7)=2\beta^2-1$ - all also from the doubling formula for cosine.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen a natural idea, I agree. I opted instead for the cyclotomic yoga rather than the trignonometric, just for pedagogical purposes, since the cyclotomic identity is very well-known and seeing that conjugates of $\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}$ are easily found by applying the Galois generator (which is what powers this particular example) I think keeps things in a consistent context rather than relying on unrelated (but awesome and slick) outside material. :-)

Comment: I agree. It is not nearly as obvious that those three cosines share a minimal polynomial - in comparison to the conjugate pairs of roots of unity that is. It is a recurring exercise in field extension theory that if $t$ is a zero of the polynomial $q(x)$ from your answer, then $t^2-2$ is another. This also follows from the doubling formula of cosines as $t=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=2\cos(2\pi/7)$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.